# Programming with dplyr - temporarily renaming columns using !!/UQ()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have read "Programming with dplyr" and have succeeded in writing my first functions using dplyr pipes and bare variable names.

For the sake of readability as well as the use of non-dyplr functions using do(), I rename the columns at the beginning of the script, perform calculations, and return the dataframe with an additional calculated variable. The problem arises when trying to return to the original variable names.

```
require(dplyr)
require(rlang)

myfun <- function(df, var1) {

  var1 <- enquo(var1)

  # Rename column of interest
  df <- df %>% rename(tempname = UQ(var1))

  # Calculate mean of column of interest
  df <- df %>% mutate(calc = tempname*2)

  # Rename column of interest back to original name
  df <- df %>% rename(UQ(var1) = tempname)

}

test <- myfun(mtcars, cyl)
```

This is the error thrown:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  # Rename column of interest back to original name
  df <- df %>% rename(UQ(var1) ="
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: For assignment to a quasiquoted variable, you use `:=` instead of `=`. I can't explain it better than the docs for `:=` can